# unable to add new software to Eclipse am using Firefox and latest Java jdk and jre

Tags: java, eclipse

github of which I am a member appears to block my connection to it's IP address with message:-
Connect to 127.0.0.1:8082 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: when attempting to update Eclipse with new software I have installed the latest Java jdk and jre both reported successful

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is your own machine.

Comment: no that is the IP of the git site where the code I need to access is. The message:- Connect to 127.0.0.1:8082 [/127.0.0.1] failed: is the last part of the error log file generated when the installation of the software from git is attempted

Comment: To move this along, I will reiterate that 127.0.0.1 is an IP address for your own machine. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost#Name_resolution

Comment: Hi All, the problems are now solved with the help of a friend of mine, the problem was related to my firewall blocking downloads. the software is now fully working thank you to all who assisted